# Flutter Mobx There are no observables detected in the builder function

Tags: flutter, mobx

Hi I got simple obseverable for testing loading state.

```
abstract class _AccountStore with Store {
  @observable
  bool loadingButtonStatus = false;


  @observable
  bool get loading => loadingButtonStatus;


  @action
  Future updateAccount(formData) async {
    loadingButtonStatus = true;

    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000)).then((future) {
      loadingButtonStatus = false;
    }).catchError((e) {
      loadingButtonStatus = false;
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

here is my widget

```
AccountStore store = AccountStore();

Observer(
  name: 'loading_button',
  builder: (_) => LoadingButton(
        loading: store.loading,
        text: Text('Save'),
        onPressed: () {
          store.updateAccount({});
        },
))
```

But everytime i run the code it always return me: `There are no observables detected in the builder function`

I've tried changed use `store.loadingButtonStatus` still the same.

any solution?

thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I had same issue but above answer didn't working for me and also Code was correct.
my `part` was not updated.

just run this command in terminal

`flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

I hope this will work.

Comment: Worked for me too! By the way, sometimes `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` works better too. Give it a go!

Answer (score 8):

If you use a getter you are required to use @computed.

```
  @observable
  bool _loadingButtonStatus = false;


  @computed
  bool get loading => _loadingButtonStatus;
```

Answer (score 4):

I also have seen this error. Because store_name.g.dart not update.

just run scrip flutter `pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs` in terminal